# Animate and move an html element from one css grid cell to another grid cell

Tags: javascript, html, css-grid

Lets say i have a css grid "A", and css grid "B", and the html element "Z".

i want to animate the translation of the "Z" element from the cell 1 of grid "A" to the cell1 of grid "B"

is it possible?

Im simulating the appearance of doing it, but is just a really messy work around, that is not responsive.

im using the animatejs library.

1- I added and animation where the Z element translates and gradually dissapear (just putting opacity to 0) towards the final location (B grid)

2- On animation end, a callback get called, and trough it im creating and appending child node  with a new Z element to the B grid.

i did the translation by trial and error till I got in place, but of course this is not responsive, the "flying" of the Z element goes anywhere on screen resize XD

Any help is greatly appreciated